# CSS is forcing Fancybox to open too small (height)

Tags: css, fancybox, zurb-foundation

Hoping this jumps out at someone...

I'm using `Fancybox 1.3 w/Foundation`. The issue I'm having is something in the Foundation CSS is forcing my `Fancybox` pop-up to render too small. When I inspect the `HTML` on the rendered page, I see an inline style setting the height at `175px`...

I'm stumped. If I remove the Foundation `CSS` file the problem goes away. I'm guessing I need to change something in the Height attribute but haven't had any luck.

Sample:
http://198.cmsintelligence.com/site/about-us (click 'play this video')

Comment: Could you provide us some code?

Comment: Editing my answer below momentarily - I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more code it's hard to debug in dev tools.  But I believe your culprit is here: `#fancybox-inner object {`

In DEV tools that ID is applying 100% height to an object, which is what is loading your video.  The object itself has a height value of 600px, but it's being overridden because that ID above also has `!important` on the height.

Also the height of 175px you mentioned, that inline styling is being generated dynamically based on content nested deeper within.  I don't believe the fault is there.

---

**EDIT:** Got it!

I have highlighted the culprits in an image below.  The first is on Line 20 of fancybox.css - the last two line 1 of foundation.min.css (no doubt a huge reset rule).  Override these in some way and you'll be golden.

```
#fancybox-inner embed, #fancybox-inner object {
height: 100% !important;
}

object, embed {
height: 100%;
}

img, object, embed {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/fancyboxbug.jpg/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for your help :)

I removed the height:auto and height:100% from the foundation css file and it worked!!

Comment: @LarryC great!  I suspected the fancybox line would be fine but in dev tools it broke.  Probably because it needed to be closed and reopened in order to evaluate correctly.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, maybe you've tried it since it's pretty in your face. Like you said, the inline style is making it 175px so why not override it in your Foundatino CSS.

```
div#fancybox-wrap{
    height: 480px;
}
```

You can always add !important at the end of the height(ex. height: 480px !important;) to force it to be that height always, or use em (ex. height: 3em;) to make it fluid and change depending on the screen size your viewer is using. Again all newbie things since I'm not that vintage in this field but maybe that helps in some way.